# docker macvlan network dhcp dns on production network

Tags: docker, networking

we re running a docker swarm with 3 nodes (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Docker 18.09.2).
I ve created a macvlan network "CONTAINER" on one of the nodes "Swarm01".

I can connect new containers to network "CONTAINER" on Swarm01 and ping it.
But i want to use our external production dhcp / dns server which is in the same subnet as the network "CONTAINER" (192.168.101.0/24).

Is this possible and if yes how can i do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Usually you use `docker run -p` to publish the container's port on the _host's_ network interfaces, and don't worry about individually assigning IP addresses to containers.  (Remember that none of the standard Docker Hub images run things like DHCP clients: they expect Docker to do all the network setup for them.)